# OSGI - How to start multiple configurations of a bundle

Tags: osgi, multiple-instances, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm new to OSGI and working with Apache Felix.

In 'Apache Felix Web Console Bundles' I can control a bundle with a start, stop, update, install and remove button.
I have made a bundle that is able to control OSGI automatically. This bundle can start, stop, install, update and remove other bundles. So I don't need the 'In 'Apache Felix Web Console Bundles' anymore.

Now I want to control multiple configurations of a bundle. In 'Apache Felix Web Console Configuration' I can create a new 'factory configuration'. I want that my bundle can create new 'factory configurations' automatically. 
Question: How can my bundle start multiple configurations of an other bundle?

**EDIT** Changed 'instances' in the second paragraph to 'configurations' 
**EDIT2** Clarified question

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not multiple instances of a bundle; these are configurations which a bundle or a service can read and behave accordingly. Further, one can have a service factory that can create a service for each matching configuration, but the bundle is singular.

Comment: Thanks. Service factory is what I was looking for.